# KakaoTalk with Wine

Tags: wine

I recently installed KakaoTalk through Wine. Everything installed without a hitch, but the program cannot run. An error dialog pops up with the message "Your system is not supported". Does anyone know about running KakaoTalk on Linux?

Using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: According to the [appdb entry](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28726), this does not seem to be well supported :(

Comment: I think that will be impossible unless they (kakaotalk devs) release a Linux version. They're not even open source as I know.

Comment: There is information how to install the KakaoTalk in Ubuntu 14.04 [here](http://blog.igk.me/2014/04/ubuntu-1404-pc-wine.html). The info is in Korean but you can translate it using machine e.g. Google translation!